# Available service types in WifiP2pDnsSdServiceInfo.newInstance

Tags: android, service, wifi-direct

I'm programming an android application that uses Wifi Direct. I'm trying to start my service and I'm calling WifiP2pDnsSdServiceInfo.newInstance. However, I have been searching for the different service types that I could use, and so far I have only found "_presence._tcp".

I understand that I should somehow find a service type that "makes sense" with what my application tries to accomplish. Can I just "invent" it? Is there any available list of protocols?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6):

Android documentation provides some info to start with in the guide [Using Network Service Discovery](http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd.html). According it the service type *specifies which protocol and transport layer the application uses. The syntax is `_<protocol>._<transportlayer>`*. So you should only use existing transports in the second part. Most commonly used are `tcp` and `udp`, of course.

As for the first part, there is a bunch of application level protocols. For example, `presence` is a messaging protocol from xmpp.org, and `ipp` is a printer service. You can find more or less complete list of the registered protocols at the [dns-sd.org site](http://www.dns-sd.org/ServiceTypes.html). Also you may have a look at [the service names registry at iana.org](http://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml).

As the DNS-based Service Discovery is a part of [Zero-configuration networking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking) which has numerous implementations, additional lists of protocols can be found on specific vendors sites. For example, here is the list of [Apple's Bonjour service types](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1312/_index.html).

I don't think there exists a single exhaustive list of protocols used worldwide. Nevertheless, I suppose you could invent your own name with a reasonably distiguishable underlying structure (acronyms and/or semantics) - just search through the Internet and make sure your name does not appear in relation to Zeroconf and DNS-SD.